# Hosts file not working properly

Tags: iis, localhost

I have a site on my test machine I want to bind into IIS with hosts file.
It's not that I haven't done it before, but this time the page is blank when I load it and chrome says the web page is not available.
In the dev tools Network tab I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED and the weird part is that I've entered a domain name in hosts file associated with 127.0.0.1 address. The same site loads when I add virtual directory and access it via localhost.

**UPDATE**
Screenshoot of the web site, bindings and dev tools network tab.
http://oi59.tinypic.com/6zsfau.jpg

I have also tried loading with Firefox and IE, but same results.
Have no idea what might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's 3 options I can think of:

1. Check that your binding in iis is set to "All Unassigned" for the IP address (displays in IIS as  "*")
2. Alternatively bind to a specific ip address and use that ip address in the hosts file
3. Check that your hosts file encode in ANSI

hope this helps

Comment: "All Unassigned" was selected at first and I have tried specific IP too to no avail, but when I entered this IP it displays IIS welcome picture and encode to ANSI doesn't work too.

Comment: can you ping the host name? also if you could put up a screenshot of your site and bindings would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the host name, I forgot to mention that. Added screenshoot.